# What's the most efficient way to replace one string at one location with a certain string at another location

Tags: evil, copy-paste, multiple-cursors

Quite often I encounter the situation where I need to insert a string from a certain location to some other location.
I wanted to know your tips to get this as done as efficient as possible. My workflow so far was to go to the above string with `(evil-avy-goto-word-1-above)` copy the desired output and then to go back visually select the text I want to replace and then paste the content of the clipboard. Also keep in mind that sometimes you will have something like `large-org-file` or even separate words which you will want to replace. For example in the image below you would want to have "a really Emacs org file" standing as a result:

[image]

I have two rough ideas how to make it more efficient.

1. Create a multiple cursor at first location, go to the second location, copy the desired string, then go to the end of the first location. Somehow visually select the text between the two multiple cursors and then paste.
   Here the difficulty lies in the implementation of visual selection between two evil-mc cursors, I don't know how to do this
2. Somehow use swiper to select the upper string, paste it into the clipboard somehow and then paste the content onto the visually selected area.

What do you think is the best way to do this? If it's number one, it would be nice to know how you implemented the visual selection thing.
Or maybe you have some alternatives I haven't thought about.

Comment: Too broad. Asking for the best way to do something generally encourages opinion-based answers. This site is more for specific how-to Q & A. Consider posting your question on a discussion site such as Reddit.

Comment: maybe this article can help you [avy-can-do-anything](https://karthinks.com/software/avy-can-do-anything/)